# Post a file /contents of a file to endpoint with Formik

Tags: post, input, file-upload, axios, formik

I would like to create a form that allows the user to upload a file (a JSON object) and then post the contents of that file to an api.

I would like to see (for now just in a console log) the contents of the file I am about to post before I post it.  So the flow should go like this

- User sees a blank form with an upload file field
- User selects a file from their computer
- Once selected, I would like to log the contents of the file to the console
- Once form is submitted, I would like to post the file to an endpoint with axios

I am using the useFormik hook because I have used it elsewhere and found it more intuitive than some of Formiks other options, and because I think it will be useful for when I build a few more features, so there may be some redundant lines of code here (e.g. initialValues) but for now I'm just focused on step one - seeing the values in a file before I post them.

It seems like I should be able to upload the file, read the contents of the file, store the contents of the file in a result, then pass that result to the onSubmit callback in the eventual axios.post() request I will make.

But I don't think I'm understanding the fundamentals here.

Should I use new FormData instead of a FileReader?

Should I bother reading the contents of the file before posting?

Here's my current code:

```
import { useFormik } from 'formik';


export const MyUploadPerfectAssetForm = () => {

    const onChange = (event: any) => {

        const file = event.target.files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (e) => {
            // The file's text will be printed here
            console.log(e.target?.result)
            const result = e.target?.result;
            console.log("logging result from reader.onload " + result)
            return result;
        };

        //shows the files values properly
        reader.readAsText(file);


    }

        //redundant for now?
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            name: null,
            tags: null,
            type: null,
            s3URL: null,
            thumbnailImageURL: null,
        },

        onSubmit: (values, result) => {

            console.log("logging values" + JSON.stringify(values))
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));


            console.log("logging values from onSubmit " + JSON.stringify(values))

            const uploadPerfectAsset = async (perfectAssetValues: any) => {

                //there will be an axios post request here, 

                console.log("upload perfect asset ran")
                console.log("testing uploadPerfectAsset with result from onChange file reader result" + JSON.stringify(perfectAssetValues))
            }

            uploadPerfectAsset(result)
        },


    });

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <input id="file"
                        name="test"
                        type="file"
                        onChange={onChange}></input>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button></div>
            </form>
        </div >
    );
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there mate  A couple of small changes are needed:

- add `file` to initialState
- move `onChange` function to after the hook `useFormik()` and add `formik.setFieldValue("file", file);` to set the value
- remove argument `perfectAssetValues` from function `uploadPerfectAsset()` - it's unnecessary

```
export const MyUploadPerfectAssetForm = () => {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      name: null,
      tags: null,
      type: null,
      s3URL: null,
      thumbnailImageURL: null,
      file: null
    },

    onSubmit: (values) => {
      console.log("logging values from onSubmit ", values);

      const uploadPerfectAsset = async () => {
        //there will be an axios post request here,

        console.log("upload perfect asset ran");
        console.log(
          "File info: ",
          JSON.stringify(
            {
              fileName: values.file.name,
              type: values.file.type,
              size: `${values.file.size} bytes`
            },
            null,
            2
          )
        );
      };

      uploadPerfectAsset();
    }
  });

  const onChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    formik.setFieldValue("file", file);
    const reader = new FileReader();

    // temporarily show file contentx
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      // The file's text will be printed here
      const result = e.target.result;
      console.log("logging result from reader.onload " + result);
      return result;
    };

    //shows the files values properly
    reader.readAsText(file);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <input id="file" name="test" type="file" onChange={onChange}></input>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-c85rz?file=/index.js:1136-1603)

Comment: Thanks Ro.  If I could go back, my whole question would have been different - I was misunderstanding the initial problem I was hoping to solve for - but your notes were still quite helpful in confirming a few key points.  Thanks!